# How to escape character '.' in python string replacement via the operator %

Tags: python, string, formatting

I want to do the following

```
"@file %(unitname).C" % {'unitname':'Test'}
```

but it complains about the '.C'. How can I escape the '.' character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. You fix the format specifier.

```
"@file %(unitname)s.C" % {'unitname':'Test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is,

```
"@file {unitname}.C".format(unitname='Test')
```

This may be preferable, since `format()` will be the new standard in Python 3.